# Not able to select the dropdown value and How do I display the dynamic field after selecting each dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button called Add partner. When you click on this button then it will display dynamic row something like this.

[image]

After displaying the row, I clicked on first select Dropbox and I choose `Bank two`.

[image]

Now notice here, If I clicked on add bank then first select dropdown will autofill display with the value of the first-row select. I mean I selected `Bank two` then `Bank two` will be selected.

[image]

If I change it from `Bank two` to `Bank three` from the first row then it will also change the in the second row of the first select dropdown. For example

[image]

This above scenario is working perfectly for me. There is no issue.

Now Let's talk about the issue.
If I click on again `Add partner` button then it will display the new row with a ID number 3. something like this

[image]

Now on ID 3, I am not able to change the `Bank three` from the dropdown. I have to do the above scenario on each ID. This is my first issue.

My second issue is on the status dropdown. Each option has a different field. I mean, If I select `Status one` then one input field will display. something like this.

[image]

Now Every time I have to display the field if the user selects the status.
for example. I clicked on add bank and select the status but it's removing the first remark.
[image]

My expected output is

[image]

Let me know if need more explanation in this. Would you help me out with this issue?

```js
$(document).on('change', '.fileStatus', function() {
  var fileStatus = $('.fileStatus option:selected').val();
  $('.fileStatus').val(fileStatus);
})

$(document).ready(function() {

  // $('.fileStatus').on('change', '.fileStatus', function(){

  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".dynamicform"); //Fields wrapper

  var add_button = $(".click_partner"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  a = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment

      a++;
      //$("input[id^=medication_name]").focus();
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class=" custom_fields medication_info" data-id="' + inner(a, 2) + '"><div class=" row"><div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="label" id="unique">ID ' + x + ':</div></div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="order[]" value="user-10-' + inner(a, 2) + '" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="1">Bank one</option><option value="2">Bank two</option><option value="3">Bank three</option></select></div> </div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><a href="#" class="new_add_bank bankLink" id="' + x + '">Add Bank</a> <div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="">Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank Three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control pp_fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Status</option> <option value="1">Status one</option><option value="2">Status two</option><option value="3">Status Three</option></select></div></div>  <div class="i-imgset remove_field"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.click_partner').closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x++;
  });

  $(wrapper).on('click', '.new_add_bank', function() {
    var innercoutner = $(this).closest('.medication_info').find('.medication_info').children('.row').length + 1;
    var c = $(this).closest('.medication_info').attr('data-id');

    var fileStatus = $('.fileStatus:last option:selected').val();
    // alert(fileStatus);

    $(this).closest('.row').append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="  medication_info"><div class=" row"><div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "></div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="order[]" value="user-10-' + c + '-' + inner(innercoutner, 2) + '" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="1">Bank one</option><option value="2">Bnak two</option><option value="3">Bank three</option></select></div> </div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="">Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control pp_fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Status</option> <option value="1">Status one</option><option value="2">Status two</option><option value="3">Status Three</option></select></div></div><div class="i-imgset remove_field"> <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');
    $('.fileStatus:last').val(fileStatus);

  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.medication_info').remove();
    x--;
  });

  // increment==============================================
  function inner(k, width, t) {
    t = t || '0';
    k = k + '';
    /* 
        return n.length >= ? n : new Array(w widthidth - n.length + 1).join(z) + n; */
    return k.length >= width ? k : new Array(width - k.length + 1).join(t) + k;
  }

});


$(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus', function(event) {
  //alert($(this).val());
  $(".input-wrapper").remove();
  if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '1')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '2')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Date</label><input type="text" name="reasonDate[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Time</label><input type="text" name="time[]"  class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  }
});
```

```css
.i-imgset {
  width: 30px;
}

.i-imgset img {
  width: 100%;
}

.bankLink {
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="click_partner"> <input type="button" name="parner" value="Add Partner"></div>
  <div class="dynamicform">

  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @cssyphus, May I know what's wrong with the code? I am using the same code and run on local shot after that I take the screenshot. I will correct form my side also.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main issues.

The first: Your delegated event on **.pp_fileStatus** is wrong because you use global selector instead of local selectors. For instance:

```
$('.pp_fileStatus').val()
```

instead of:

```
$(this).val()
```

The second issue suffers the same issue but for the delegated event on **.fileStatus**. The new one is:

```
$(document).on('change', '.fileStatus', function() {
    var fileStatus = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.medication_info .fileStatus').val(fileStatus);
})
```

```js
var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper = $(".dynamicform"); //Fields wrapper

var add_button = $(".click_partner"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
a = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment

        a++;
        //$("input[id^=medication_name]").focus();
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class=" custom_fields medication_info" data-id="' + inner(a, 2) + '"><div class=" row"><div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="label" id="unique">ID ' + x + ':</div></div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="order[]" value="user-10-' + inner(a, 2) + '" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="1">Bank one</option><option value="2">Bank two</option><option value="3">Bank three</option></select></div> </div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><a href="#" class="new_add_bank bankLink" id="' + x + '">Add Bank</a> <div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="">Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank Three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control pp_fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Status</option> <option value="1">Status one</option><option value="2">Status two</option><option value="3">Status Three</option></select></div></div>  <div class="i-imgset remove_field"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.click_partner').closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x++;
});

$(wrapper).on('click', '.new_add_bank', function() {
    var innercoutner = $(this).closest('.medication_info').find('.medication_info').children('.row').length + 1;
    var c = $(this).closest('.medication_info').attr('data-id');

    var fileStatus = $('.fileStatus:last option:selected').val();
    // alert(fileStatus);

    $(this).closest('.row').append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="  medication_info"><div class=" row"><div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "></div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="order[]" value="user-10-' + c + '-' + inner(innercoutner, 2) + '" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="1">Bank one</option><option value="2">Bnak two</option><option value="3">Bank three</option></select></div> </div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="">Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control pp_fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Status</option> <option value="1">Status one</option><option value="2">Status two</option><option value="3">Status Three</option></select></div></div><div class="i-imgset remove_field"> <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');
    $('.fileStatus:last').val(fileStatus);

});

$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.medication_info').remove();
    x--;
});

// increment==============================================
function inner(k, width, t) {
    t = t || '0';
    k = k + '';
    /*
     return n.length >= ? n : new Array(w widthidth - n.length + 1).join(z) + n; */
    return k.length >= width ? k : new Array(width - k.length + 1).join(t) + k;
}

$(document).on('change', '.fileStatus', function() {
    var fileStatus = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.medication_info .fileStatus').val(fileStatus);
})

$(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus', function(event) {
    //alert($(this).val());
    var operation = 'append';
    var ele = $(this).closest('.row');
    if ($(this).closest('.row').find('.medication_info').length != 0) {
        operation = 'after';
        ele = ele.find('.i-imgset:first');
        ele.siblings(".input-wrapper").remove();
    } else {
        ele.find(".input-wrapper").remove();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == '1') {
        ele[operation]('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
    } else if ($(this).val() == '2') {
        ele[operation]('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Date</label><input type="text" name="reasonDate[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
    } else {
        ele[operation]('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Time</label><input type="text" name="time[]"  class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
    }
});
```

```css
.i-imgset {
    width: 30px;
}

.i-imgset img {
    width: 100%;
}

.bankLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="click_partner"> <input type="button" name="parner" value="Add Partner"></div>
    <div class="dynamicform">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this. There are some internet issues at my home due to heavy rain.

Comment: in the new_add_bank function  check this line $(this).closest('.row').append('        . You used this and in my code event.target

Comment: Yes, I checked each and every steps and It's working. but I found one issue in your snippet or might be mine issue. Can you help me out with this also? The issue is, I clicked on add partner button and I fill all the information but I forgot to select the "Status" and directly clicked on add bank. Now If I select the status from the first row then check  fields position is changed check this https://prnt.sc/o949qg and If I select the status from the second row then it's displaying like https://prnt.sc/o94b6x

Comment: Oh!. I really appreciate your efforts and help. It's working perfectly. I want to know about if condition which is used in the $(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus...... Why I am asking because I have one row which is static  ID 1 and if you click on Add partner then it will start from ID2. It's my fault not to explain it before.

Comment: The if condition is very easy to understand: go up to the row, if the first. If there is a medication_info block append after the first i-imgset else append at the end. You have a medication_info  block inside another one. In one case you need to remove siblings in the other case you need to remove the last input-wrapper before adding/inserting after.... In this case the ID does make any difference. It's only a matter of how to find the best pattern going up and down. ele[operation] in this way you are executing the jquery append or after:  ele.append... or ele['append]...